# Which Java datatype is suitable to handle rowversion datatype of SqlServer?

Tags: java, sql-server, dropwizard, jdbi

Sql Server have rowversion datatype to use as optimistic concurrency. I am facing problem to use in Dropwizard Jdbi project(written in Java).

Currently I am using this below line of code to convert the rowversion sql server datatype into java. This line written in DAO mapper(mapper convert database result set into java models.)

```
ByteArray  version = getBytes("version")
```

Please help me on this to figure out the correct way to handle this type of case.

Comment: What's wrong with ByteArray? The [rowversion documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) says, "_A nonnullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a binary(8) column. A nullable rowversion column is semantically equivalent to a varbinary(8) column._"

Answer (score 1):

A byte array or an unsigned long.  The 8 bytes are a base-256 representation of a monotonically increasing whole number.  Which is identical to a big endian (aka network byte order) 64-bit unsigned integer.

eg

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists t

create table t(id int identity, rv rowversion)

insert into t default values
insert into t default values
insert into t default values
insert into t default values


SELECT *, CAST(rv as bigint)
FROM T
```

outputs

```
id          rv                 
----------- ------------------ --------------------
1           0x000000000000085E 2142
2           0x000000000000085F 2143
3           0x0000000000000860 2144
4           0x0000000000000861 2145

(4 rows affected)
```